# How to extract column headings without using libraries?

Tags: r, jupyter

I have the following code, but it prints numbers when I hoped to get the column headings.

```
train <- read.csv("Regression_train.csv" )
colnames<-colnames(train)
df<-as.data.frame(colnames)
n <-length(df$colnames)
cat('ncols',n,'\n')
for ( i in 1:n)
{
   colname <-df$colnames[i]
   cat(colname,'\n')
}
```

Where the numbers are coming from?
How can I get the correct colname?

[Update]

[image: run output]

[Update]

The following works ok

```
n <-length(colnames)
cat('ncols',n,'\n')
for ( i in 1:n)
{
       colname <-colnames[i]
       cat(colname, '\n')
 }
```

Comment: when I run your code, it works fine... prints all column names. Or what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: After the edit it no longer prints the numbers. If you want the colnames any of `colnames<-colnames(train)` (in the code) or `colnames<-names(train)` will do it. I really don't understand the problem, can you post expected output? Instead of `train` to which we don't have access, post an example with one of the built-in data sets, such as `colnames<-colnames(mtcars)`

Comment: What is the output of `print(colnames)`?

Comment: It prints the column names

Comment: Shall I delete this question? I am not sure it adds value.

Comment: weird... for me it also works fine with `class(colname)` added. Are you sure your colnames are not corrupt? are you reading in the header as well?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the column names.